# How to call a function within a function from another function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

I have defined a function within another function in python and now I would like to call the inner function. Is this possible, in python?
How do I call `func2` from `func3`?

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("Hello!")

def func3():
    # Enter code to call func2 here
```

Comment: You can not, since a function is procedural, you define the function when you a specific `func2()` when you call `func1()`. If you call `func1()` multiple times, you will define several `func2`s. Furthermore since it is procedural, it is possible that `func2` is never declared (in an `if` statement). Here you do not return the function, so unless with debugger-like hacking, that would be close to impossible.

Comment: But why have you defined it inside another function? If you want to call `func2` without calling `func1`, then it should be outside `func1`. Maybe your both functions are better fit for single class??

Comment: Search the python dokumentation, google and SO for topics that might answer your question before asking -
 you could have found f.e. this: [short-description-of-the-scoping-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: What do **actually** want to achieve ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I will keep that in mind next time :), Evyatar I was trying something dirty, I had added those functions in the run() function of Thread Class, it was something hacky, dirty and wrong but I was curious nevertheless.

Comment: I'm not recommending it, but there is a way: see my updated answer.

Comment: @mhawke oh!, that's beautiful! and no I am not using that in my source code, I was just curious how much we could really bend Python. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.

I'm not sure why you would want to do that. If you want to be able to call `func2()` from outside `func1()`, simply define `func2()` at an appropriate outer scope.

One way that you could do it is to pass a parameter to `func1()` indicating that it should invoke `func2()`:

```
def func1(call_func2=False):
    def func2():
        print("Hello!")
    if call_func2:
        return func2()

def func3():
    func1(True)
```

but since that requires modification to the existing code, you might as well move `func2()` to the same scope as `func1()`.

---

I don't recommend that you do this, however, with some indirection you can reach into the `func1()` function object and access it's code object. Then using that code object access the code object for the inner function `func2()`. Finally call it with `exec()`:

```
>>> exec(func1.__code__.co_consts[1])
Hello!
```

To generalise, if you had multiple nested functions in an arbitrary order and you wanted to call a specific one by name:

```
from types import CodeType
for obj in func1.__code__.co_consts:
    if isinstance(obj, CodeType) and obj.co_name == 'func2':
        exec(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's go into little deep and explore it :

You can do this via three methods :

> First method:

Just return the nested function from main function so return will become the caller of nested function:

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("Hello!")
    return func2()


def func3():
    return func1()

func3()
```

output:

```
Hello!
```

> Second method : Even you can pass argument directly to nested
>   function:

```
Using Closure concept :
def func1():
    def func2(x):
        print("Hello {}".format(x))
    return func2

closure=func1()
def func3():
    return closure('bob')

func3()
```

Look above example , Main function is not accepting any parameter but nested function have one parameter so here i directly pass the argument to nested function.

> Third method :

You can try this little hacky thing :

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("Hello")
    return func2


def func3():
    return func1()()

func3()
```