# Dictionary Functions: Can you assign an argument to a "Tier 2" function?

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for time spent on this enquiry. 
I am curious to know if the following is possible.
For the below code, is there syntax that will allow you to define 
an argument for a function (referenced by a dictionary) that is outside of the functions' "tier"?

For this example:
I have a main function, `mainFunction(key)`.
I can call either mainFunction0 or 1 with the last line `mainFunction(mainReferences[0]`)
IE changing the key to either a 0 or 1 concatenates the reference
for the function name to be called.

But what if... I want mainFunction0 to have some sort of argument
(one or multiple arguments), that I want to reference with,

```
mainFunction(mainReferences[0])
```

I have tried the following, but none seem to work.

```
mainFunction(mainReferences[0])(1)

mainFunction(mainReferences[0], 1)
```

Where the additional "1" in either case is the input for "testArg0" 
within function `mainFunction0(testArg0)`.

Can this be done?
If so, is it also possible to enter multiple "outside of tier" arguments?

Cheers!

```
def mainFunction(key):

    def mainFunction0(testArg0):
        if testArg0 == 1:
            print("main function 1")
        else:
            pass

    def mainFunction1():
        print("main function 1")

    locals()['mainFunction' + key]() 

mainReferences  = ["0", "1"]

mainFunction(mainReferences[0])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function within a function from another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049474/how-to-call-a-function-within-a-function-from-another-function-in-python)

Comment: Yes, the question I asked was indeed very similar to that other article, but I had a specific need to solve this issue with a dictionary. The other article, while very similar, would not have answered my question. @blhsing was able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make `mainFunction` accept variable arguments:

```
def mainFunction(key, *args, **kwargs):

    def mainFunction0(testArg0):
        if testArg0 == 1:
            print("main function 1")
        else:
            pass

    def mainFunction1():
        print("main function 1")

    locals()['mainFunction' + key](*args, **kwargs)

mainReferences  = ["0", "1"]

mainFunction(mainReferences[0], 1)
```

or make `mainFunction` return a function object and let the caller make the actual call:

```
def mainFunction(key):

    def mainFunction0(testArg0):
        if testArg0 == 1:
            print("main function 1")
        else:
            pass

    def mainFunction1():
        print("main function 1")

    return locals()['mainFunction' + key]

mainReferences  = ["0", "1"]

mainFunction(mainReferences[0])(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing.
The top example you provided did the trick. Can you please also explain the bottom example, as I can't see what you did different from the original example I gave?
Cheers!